# C++ Builder 11 windows10 .exe program runs only on my computer Error rtl280.bpl Is Either Not Designed To Run On Windows Or It Contains An Error

Tags: dll, exe, c++builder

I'm working on a program using C++Builder 11.

The program works perfectly on my computer, but it doesn’t work on any other computer. When I try to run it on other computer, I have this error

[image]

> Error rtl280.bpl Is Either Not Designed To Run On Windows Or It Contains An Error

I have tried to remove it and add it again, but I have the same problem.

Comment: Error `0xc000035a` is `STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_WIN_64`, it means you are trying to load a 64bit DLL into a 32bit process. But the DLL path in the error message suggests a 32bit program is being used. Did you copy the wrong BPL into that folder? Since the program is linked to external Runtime Packages, you have to use 32bit BPLs with a 32bit app, and 64bit BPLs with a 64bit app. Otherwise, turn off Runtime Packages in your app's project options.

Comment: Thank's for your answer Remy